# Insert into table with dynamic ID javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, database

I have a javascript function that creates a table and returns a list of names.  each name is an a href to a mobile website.  I add an id to each a href tag.  the id tag is `id="player + counter"`.  the results in `player1` `player2` etc.  in the column beside each name an add button appears.  that button has a function to add the name to a database.  i call it like this:

```
addName(document.getElementById('player + counter').value);
```

I get no errors.  everything seems to work fine, except when i look in the database at the added value, it is not the name, it says undefined.  i cannot figure this out. everything looks just fine.  i assume its because the element by id is created dynamically and isnt on the page to begin.  does this make sense???  i can elaborate more if needed, but everything seems to be working just fine.  why does it insert an undefined value?

sorry, i was distracted when i was writing the question. there are no syntax errors that i can see. how i actually write it is as follows:

```
onclick("addPlayer(document.getElementById(' + "'txtListName').value, document.getElementById('player" + counter + "').value)")
```

if there was something wrong with a quotation or something i dont believe it would work the way it does. i mean when i inspect the elements it works perfectly the a tags id's increment perfectly, player1 player 2 etc. player is just that, the word player, it isnt a variable

Comment: are you trying to get the text in your link? <a href=''>Foobar</a> .. eg. 'Foobar'

Comment: Please show us your actual relevant HTML and javscript.  From the one piece of code you showed, this: `addName(document.getElementById('player + counter').value);` should be this: `addName(document.getElementById('player' + counter).value);` and `id="player + counter".` should be this: `id="player" + counter`.

Comment: @jfriend00. Sorry, I've just now seen you already wrote my answer, 12 min' ago.

Comment: @gdoron - I put my issue in a comment because it wasn't clear if this error was in the actual code or just a typing mistake in posting the question.  This is what happens when people asking questions don't show us the real HTML and the real code.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your error:

Change:

```
addName(document.getElementById('player + counter').value);
```

To:

```
addName(document.getElementById('player' + counter).value);
```

Answer (score 0):

And if gdoron's good suggestion doesn't work try...

```
 addName(document.getElementById(player + counter).value);
```

Because we can't see your code. Good luck.